# Moving modulus operator to the other side of the equation

Tags: math, modulus

I have a mathematical problem that is part of my programming problem

I have a statement like

```
a = b%30;
```

How can I calculate `b` in terms of `a`?

I gave it a thought but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 8):

By definition,

```
b == 30*n + a
```

for some integer `n`.

Note that there are multiple `b` values that can give you the same `a`:

```
>>> b = 31
>>> b % 30
1
>>> b = 61
>>> b % 30
1
```

Comment: so there isn't a specific way to go about determining value of b using a in this case right?

Comment: If `%` is the remainder operator as found in most programming languages, then your solution is incorrect for `a` between -29 and -1. Even if it is the modulus, your solution `b == 30*n + a` does not work for a>=30.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Presumably `a` will always be in the range `[0,29]`.

Comment: @ShenoyTinny If you have no further information about `a` and `b`, then you can't determine their unique values.

Comment: Why presume when it is so simple to give the shape of solutions for all values of `a`?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Because `a` is assigned to `b%30`, which cannot take on any values besides those in the aforementioned range.

Comment: @arshajii In “math” (the question is tagged “math”), the `=` sign denotes equality, not assignment. In most programming languages, `a` can be negative after executing the equivalent of the C assignment `a = b % 30;`

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yes, some languages can give you an `a` in the range `[-29, 29]`; however the solution above is still valid in this range. The `=` sign here almost certainly denotes assignment, as is evidenced by the semicolon and *"I have a statement like"*.

Comment: @arshajii “the solution above is still valid in this range” No it is not.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Do you have a counter-example?

Comment: Counter-example: a = -1, n = 1, 30 * n + a = 29, 29 % 30 is not -1.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Well what is your `b`, in that case? If `b` is `-1`, for instance, then `a = -1` and `n` can be `0`. Why have you chosen `n = 1`?

Comment: I applied your formula `b == 30*n + a` for a = -1, n = 1. It gave me b == 29, and the value 29 for b does not satisfy `b == 30*n + a`. What do you call a counter-example if it is not a triple of values for a, b and n that show that your formula does not work?

Comment: @PascalCuoq I think you misunderstood. I said *"for some integer `n`"* in that there exists some value for `n` (which we may not know) that will satisfy that formula. In your example, `n=1` may or may not work, but there will always be *some* `n` value that will work. This is by definition of the [modulus operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). Of course, if we are only given `a`, we cannot deduce `n` or `b`, since multiple `b` values can map to the same `a` value.

Answer (score 3):

First, obviously, there are in general several solutions for `b` for a given `a`.

If `%` is the remainder operator found in most programming languages, then the sign of `a` is critical. You know that this is a website for programming questions, right?

If |a|>=30, then there are no solutions

If a = 0, the solutions are the multiples of 30.

If 0 < a < 30, the solutions are all the `b` such that `b = 30 * k + a` for some positive integer `k`.

If -30 < a < 0, the solutions are all the `b` such that `b = - (30 * k - a)` for some positive integer `k`.

Comment: Yes, I retract that comment. [-29, 29] is the correct range, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, by definition

```
b == 30*n + a
```

Because of the constraints imposed by `b%30`, `a` must be between 0 and 29

However b is unbounded. there are (infinitely) many `b` for each `a`

Therefore you must have some other equation to apply to `b` or `n` to get a clear answer.  I will call this `f(b)`

To solve for `b` programmatically you would also need a valid range for `n`, or at least a value to start at and a direction to move in:

```
# an example function, this would be unique to whatever your problem is
function f(b)
    return 100 <= b <= 1000

n = 0  # or whatever your start is
while not f(b)  # could also be f(n) depending on your needs
    n += 1  # or whatever your direction is
    b == 30*n + a
```

or if you want to collect several b's across a range of n

```
# an example function, this would be unique to whatever your problem is
function f(b)
    return 100 <= b <= 1000

results = array()
for n = 0 to 1e9 # or whatever your range is
    b == 30*n + a
    if f(b) then results.append(b)
```